# Generating set of random elements with further generation of 'one by one'

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I am generating elements that have random data attributes like so :

```
generateCards : function(n)
        {
            var actions = ['press', 'blue-right', 'blue-left', 'red-right', 'red-left'],
                i = n,
                ran,
                actions_cpy = actions.slice();

            for (; i--;) {
                ran = (Math.random() * actions_cpy.length)|0;
                $('#container-game-mobile').prepend(
                   $('<div>', {
                     // remove and return a random string from the array
                     'class': 'game-card-mobile',
                     'data-action': actions_cpy.splice(ran, 1)[0]
                   })
                );
                // load the array backup with values when it is empty
                if (actions_cpy.length === 0) {
                    actions_cpy = actions.slice();
                }
            }
        }
```

Function works in a way where there are more or less equal amounts of each data atribute from actions array. I initially generate 10 elements so `n = 10` due to the nature of application every time an action is performed on a `.game-card-mobile` I destroy it and need to generate new one so, call above function but now with `n = 1` . Issue here is that, I somehow need to call elements that will still differ, so prevent 'blue-right' appearing over and over again.

Comment: Does `ran` still return a random number when `n = 1` ?

Comment: @guest271314 yes it does

Comment: `actions_cpy.splice(ran, 1)[0]` not return random item from `actions_cpy` while `ran` return random number and `n = 1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit confusing, but I think I get the problem.

You need a function to get your actions, that function will **return** a random of this array, to this function, pass a **param** of your last actions randomised and if your random is the same as your last random, **call the same function again**, it will prevent your problem.